# Is there a way to group entities by BLOCK in a dxf file with ezdxf library?

Tags: python, autocad, dxf, ezdxf

I want to parse and group all entities inside a dxf file by BLOCK and then print each BLOCK's name with the entities that make up that block underneath.
Is there a way to do this using the ezdxf library (maybe the groupby() function) ?
Entities that do not make up a block don't need to be grouped nor printed.

I've tried using the groupby() function but didn't find a way to group by BLOCKS

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import ezdxf

def main(filename: str) -> None:
    doc = ezdxf.readfile(filename)
    for block in doc.blocks:
        print(f"Block name: {block.name}")
        print(f"BLOCK entity: {str(block.block)}")
        print(f"ENDBLK entity: {str(block.endblk)}")
        print("Block content entities:")
        print("-----------------------")
        for entity in block:
            print(f"  {str(entity)}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main("your.dxf")
```

Please read the docs: https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/